# How is it possible for an AI to interact with someone without a computer screen?

Tags: agi

As you can see, there is no computer screen for the computer, thus the AI cannot display an image of itself.  How is it possible for it to see and talk to someone?[image]

Comment: There are very many ways how a can interact with the computer,apart from the screen.Voice Recognition and webcam.But you're question lacks some in depth research.

Comment: So an AI does not need a computer screen in order to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many communication methods that could be used by an artificial intelligence. Artificial intelligence can be integrated to various things including robots, phones, IoT and many others. Primary ways of human communications are  either visual or auditory, therefore an natural way for it to communicate with a human is through voice, text, images and videos. The output does not have to be limited to screens but can be anything from refrigerators to speakers.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Would a camera with facial recognition and speaker make the AI be able to see and talk?

Comment: If so, does facial recognition helps AI see someone with better quality?

Comment: For any visual communication, it fouls use sensors such as cameras as you mentioned or others such as inferred, temperature sensor and etc to detect the environment

Comment: so is that a no to my questions?

Comment: Your question was how can AI communicate and I have explained it for you.

Comment: I mean is the camera and speaker one of the answers?

Comment: Yes definitely. You're welcome for the answers :)

Comment: Ps facial recognition helps the AI recognise people rather than "see" them better. You are obviously lacking some knowledge and research in to this topic...

Comment: of course, so even when there's no facial recognition, the AI can still see if the camera is still present

Comment: Yes i would say that statement is somewhat correct but it depends on what you define "see" as in terms of AI

Answer (score 0):

"How is it possible for it to see and talk to someone?"

OK, unfortunately this is quite vague... but I am going to try my best.

The monitor of the computer really doesn't change the ability for it to communicate. For instance, voice recognition is natural to humans along with visual factors. So sensors involving auditory elements assists the AI with this. 
Now I commented that the question was vague because you said "there is no computer screen for the computer, ****thus the AI cannot display an image of itself****.

Even though the AI can not see does not mean it can not communicate. Those who are blind still have ways of communication, just in a different manner. Sure, they can not recognize one with their own eyes, but they can by touch, and read with braille. Now compared to AI communication, the braille is to any other form of sensor.

Sorry for jumping all over the place, also I did not mean to offend anyone with my comparison... :/